# Mysql Select Code Doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql

I have my php/mysql SELECT code which doesn't return a result to what I have expected after execution of the code.
Code: [Select]

```
$sql="SELECT *FROM advert 
       WHERE ad_Type = '%{$service}%' AND
            ad_Street_No like '%{$location}%' OR
            ad_Street_Name like '%{$location}%' OR
            ad_Suburb like '%{$location}%' OR
            ad_Postcode like '%{$location}%' OR
            ad_State like '%{$location}%'";
```

The user will search on location and  the type of service available using parameters like street name,suburb, postcode and/or state in one textfield and then select a type of service from a dropdown menu. So for example  : "Select records from table 'advert' where type of service = 'e.g. hauling,digging,' located at e.g. Cardiff NSW". " something like that.

I have 2 records right now on my database :
1. Service: Hauling, Location: Cardiff NSW
2. Service: Digging , Location: Cardiff NSW

Now the problem is:

you search for "Hauling" service in "Cardiff" , will return 2 records (#1 and #2).
you search for "Digging" service in "Cardiff", will return 2 records (#1 and #2).
you search for either of the services in " Cardiff NSW", will return 0 results.

I got no idea on how to fix this. Please help me guys.  Thank you in advance.  :(  :(  :(

Best regards

Comment: Ever considered using prepared statements (http://php.net/mysqli.prepare or http://php.net/pdo.prepare)?

Comment: did you realize that you are using = in the ad_Type, and not like? is it correct to use % in the ad_Type if it's not pattern?

Comment: it was a mistake on my part, I remove the (=) use like but still doesn't return a desirable result.

Comment: Probably just a typo in the question, but there's no space after your asterisk: `SELECT *FROM` should be `SELECT * FROM`.

Comment: Ohh, I see.Thanks Sir Mike. i did not notice that.:-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, you need some brackets:

```
$sql="SELECT *FROM advert 
       WHERE ad_Type like '%{$service}%' AND
           ( ad_Street_No like '%{$location}%' OR
             ad_Street_Name like '%{$location}%' OR
             ad_Suburb like '%{$location}%' OR
             ad_Postcode like '%{$location}%' OR
             ad_State like '%{$location}%'" );
```

That will fix your first case. But you also need to think about exactly what it is you're providing : for instance if you only provide a town then you don't want to include ad_Type in your query at all.

Comment: :-), Woow! Great Sir Sam ,it works!.problem 1 and 2 are now solved. Another thing Sir is when I tried to search for "Cardiff NSW", no record found, but if only I will search on "cardiff" or "NSW", that will return something desirable.

Comment: there was a typo mistake on my part when i post this question, ad_Type = '%{$service}%' , which should be ad_Type like '%{$service}%' however after I applied your tip,it works. :-). Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM advert
        WHERE ad_Type    like '%{$service}%' 
        AND (
          ad_Street_No   like '%{$location}%' 
          OR
          ad_Street_Name like '%{$location}%' 
          OR
          ad_Suburb      like '%{$location}%'
          OR
          ad_Postcode    like '%{$location}%' 
          OR
          ad_State       like '%{$location}%'
        )";
```

Comment: thanks sir fam khan. it works, but how can i solve problem #3 - "you search for either of the services in "Cardiff NSW", will return 0 results". ?